# How is this question not programming-related?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I had a [C socket API question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45903559/1) on how to *"`connect` to an IP address that exists in [two subnets]"* and how to choose *which* one of them to connect to.
I quickly received a helpful (and correct) answer stating that the OS uses a routing table and that this most likely cannot be done programmatically and depends on OS settings.

However, afterward, it was quickly shut down because people could *"see absolutely no indication that this question is programming-related"*, despite the fact that the question had been about how to achieve a clear task programmatically, and that I had *already received* an answer to this effect, stating that such an API unfortunately does not exist.

**Now, obviously, I had no idea *beforehand* whether this can be done programmatically, or I would have already known the answer to my question.**

But people are saying that means the *question* is *off-topic* and not even programming-related?
(Presumably if there *was* such an API, it would render the exact same *question* on-topic?)

Does this mean users are expected to know the answer to their question already in order to know whether their question is on-topic?
Can someone explain this?
It seems like a pretty clear-cut socket programming question to me.

#### Edit:

I guess I should have asked this explicitly since no one has addressed this so far, but if you don't think the question belonged on Stack Overflow, then where **do** you think the appropriate site would have been?

Comment: It should be on https://superuser.com/ if it isn't directly programming related

Comment: Any mods care to chime in? I still don't understand the mod comment that *"Saying that it's not possible to do it via code is essentially the whole point."* Is the positivity or negativity of the answer supposed to affect the on-topic-ness of the question on this site, or no?

Comment: I assume they didn't comment in their capacity as mod ... let's not go down the road where a few mods determine what is on- or off-topic here and we all follow.

Comment: @rene: Cody Gray *definitely* commented in his capacity as mod (even if he somehow didn't intend to, which is unlikely). He cast the final close vote right when he came and immediately wrote his comment, and that wasn't even the 5th vote cast. If he's going to mod-hammer questions into closing then I would very much like to understand his reasoning.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I see no indication that Cody's comment would be any different had he not been a moderator. His vote was the 4rth, I would happily have added a 5th vote (again, moderator or not). Your question was off-topic, a moderator only helped speed along the closure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You don't have to word any things differently when you're saying something in a different capacity. He was clearly explaining his decision to close the question; that to me is as clear an indication as any that he was writing this as a moderator. I'm honestly not sure this is even germane to the issue though; I'm surprised it was brought up at all.

Comment: You are arguing in circles. Cody gave his reasons to cast a close vote. Those reasons are still the same with and without a binding vote. There were 3 other votes, others told you the same thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Could you address [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355740/how-is-this-question-not-programming-related?noredirect=1#comment508460_355742)/[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355740/how-is-this-question-not-programming-related?noredirect=1#comment508498_355740) (which is also in my question above)? It's actually quite the *opposite* of what others have said.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Still waiting for a response to this^

Comment: @Mehrdad: and I'm not interested in being drawn into a long drawn-out discussion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not asking for a long drawn-out discussion, I'm literally asking if the answer should affect whether the question is on-topic as Cody had said. That should be yes/no.

Answer (score 10):

I believe, there are 2 questions here:

1. In general, are questions, where the OP does not know beforehand if they are programming related, off-topic in case they turn out to be not programming related?

   I think the answer is: yes, they are off topic because they are not related to programming. The fact that the OP is not aware must not make it on-topic, otherwise any OP could claim ignorance when asking non-programming related questions.
2. Specifically, is your question programming related?

   Now, I think this is a bit more tricky. Because of the **way** you asked the question, I agree with those, who closed it. Why? Because if you have multiple network adapters, then choosing where to **route** the traffic is done by configuring the OS or specific routing softwares. You do not really expect to do this from a common application, you would expect the OS to be configured to route the traffic. Moreover, such routing has really nothing to do with sockets or a specific programming language, but these have already been explained in comments below the question.

   Were your question worded something like *"how do I **programmatically** set or determine which network adapter is used for a certain IP address under operating system X?"*, then I believe, your question would not have been closed as not programming related. Nevertheless, I still expect this modified question to be downvoted when you mention that the two networks have the same IP address range. Also, I would expect lots of comments asking for why you want to do this programmatically, when the OS can take care of this.

   Btw, obviously you can change adapter priority and routing rules under most operating systems in a programmatic way. But the exact way is entirely OS specific.

Comment: +1 thanks! It's nice to get a third-party opinion. Question about your answer though: what about the fact that I had tagged the question as `C` and `sockets`, and I was asking how to `connect` to an IP address? Do those actually indicate some kind of OS/networking configuration question to you, or do they indicate a question about how to `connect` to a particular host via `sockets` in `C`?

Comment: As I wrote, I would not expect an sw to handle these things programmatically and the the tags you chose are irrelevant to the question.  (Yeah, I know, it is hard to choose the appropriate tags if you do not know the answer.) Therefore, it is difficult to interpret your question as it is worded now as sg programming related.

Comment: If you reworded the question to make it clear 1) you want to programmatically route traffic 2) what operating system you use 3) how you can distinguish which network adapter to use if the IP addresses are the same, then I'm happy to cast a reopen vote. Obviously, you would have to un-accept the non-programming answer. However, I would still expect downvotes as the starting point (2 networks with same IP address range) seem to be the root cause of the issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) it's nice to finally see a concrete and actionable one. I've updated the question as you asked. I haven't un-accepted the answer though since it *is* a programming answer -- it simply says there is no programmatic solution.

Comment: Ouch, I think you made your question too broad by not specifying the OS (listing 3 completely different ones is pretty much the same as not specifying any) and not specifying how to distinguish between the 2 networks

Comment: Wait but why? I did specify 3 OSes (or as many as allow this) and I said I'm fine with *any* solution for distinguishing them -- whoever has an answer can pick one. I guess I could arbitrarily pick one (e.g. MAC address, index, etc.) but how would that help? It would artificially narrow the solution set when I don't have any such artificial constraints in the problem. Are you saying I should post 9 different questions for each of the 9 combinations of 3 OS x 3 distinction methods? I want to write a program that works on as many OSes as possible, not just the current OS I'm personally running.

Comment: The answer per OS will be different and lengthy in itself, so combining them into a single answer is difficult. Linux has lots of different distros and there may be differences on distro level as well. Moreover, how many people do you think there are, who know all the OS in such a great detail? As per how to distinguish between the 2 networks - I expect **you** to tell me. These are your networks, you are the one who is familiar with their details, not us.

Comment: Okay but I still don't understand, are you saying I should have 3+ questions, one for each platform? And what do you mean these are *"your"* networks? What makes you think I'm the single user of the program I'm writing? This isn't just for me, I want others to be able to use my program too. If it was just about me I would be saying "me", not "users"!

Comment: I thought you had a **specific** problem, whereby you had 2 networks connecting to a specific computer, running a specific OS. This is a type of question that is suitable for SO. If you have a general question, then I'm afraid, it may not be suitable for SO, even if it is programming related.

Comment: What? Are you saying the only questions suitable for SO are those programs that  programmers are writing for *themselves* personally? I can't be writing a cross-platform program for several users and asking about that?

Comment: I've said this before but it seems you missed this: The problem is pretty clear and specific, it's the programming problem of how to communicate with different hosts that have identical IP addresses. But **the fact that there are identical IP addresses is not itself the problem under question.** You understand this right? The question is not about the network management.

Comment: @Mehrdad no, I have not missed that, just I disagree. Your question is clear, but not specific at all. By expecting the answers to cover all OS and expecting us to suggest a method to distinguish between devices with conflicting IP addresses makes the question too broad and primarily opinion based. SO is no about discussing suggestions.

Comment: Here's what I don't understand: if I just said artificially said I want to distinguish the adapters "based on an index (0, 1, 2, ...)", would you feel it's somehow better? Even though it's a totally artificial restriction?

Comment: Nope, you would have to provide a lot more details, such as how the indexes are created, maintained, and most importantly, how do you make the IP take notice of this.

Comment: What about MAC address? (User-provided)

Answer (score 6):

As one of the close voters: The only indication that this was about the C socket API was that the word `connect` in the sentence is written in code formatting. I already explained that in the comments of the question.

Even if you get that, the question ask "How can I control what happens in such a case?", not "How can I control what happens **programmatically**?" which is a huge difference.

For me this question still reads like a network/OS configuration question and not like a programming question.

Comment: If the accepted answer had given an API (plus maybe an example) for actually doing this would you have still said this is not programming-related?

Comment: Yes. You should never judge a question by the quality/content of the answers.

Comment: The question was clearly tagged `C` and `sockets`? How come the `connect` only indication that it is asking to do something using code? That `connect` was even formatted as code, I don't see any reason to confuse it as normal word connect.

Comment: @BDL: I just don't understand. You really, honestly, genuinely see `C` and `sockets` and `connect` in the question and you think *"oh my god, I bet this is an OS network configuration question!"*? You *really* don't think this was a quick misjudgment on your part?

Comment: And for the record, Cody Gray disagree with you that the content of the answer is irrelevant. To quote him verbatim (emphasis mine), *"Saying that it's not possible to do it via code **is essentially the whole point**."* So he would've seen it as quite a different situation if there *had* been an API for doing this!

Comment: In my opinion: It is still not clear that this is about the linux socket library. [tag:sockets] is not specific to that library. Could also be `connect` from winsock or any other library. Even if we leave this point out, the question still doesn't ask for a programmatic solution: If I add an answer explaining how to configure your network interface on Windows to prevent the problem, would you accept it? It would perfectly answer the question since you never ask for Linux or for a code solution.

Comment: I'm not saying that my opinion is necessarily the correct one, I just wanted to explain why I voted to close the question. If there are other who disagree with me, feel free to reopen/write another answer here.

Comment: @BDL: *"It is still not clear that this is about the linux socket library."* Indeed, it never was. It's not about any particular library, it's about the standard socket APIs. When someone asks how to use `printf` to print an `int`, do you think they're asking about GLIBC?

Comment: @BDL: As for whether I would accept an answer telling me how to configure my network to prevent the "problem": no, I would not accept it because I'm not asking how to prevent any problem at all. The word "problem" wasn't even in the question because I don't really see this as a problem, I see it as a scenario any grandpa could get into. But if you *did* post an answer explaining how to contact the two hosts non-programmatically, I might actually accept it because it would probably help me figure out how *those* programs achieve this internally (I can always disassemble etc.).

Comment: @BDL: And I appreciate that you explained your answer, but surely you realize that it's not helpful without a sound/consistent reason behind it? The goal here is to help me (and others) figure out where to ask each question in the future, after all. So far I have no idea. I've explained why pretty much *none* of your rationales seem to be consistent with the situation (e.g. above^) but it seems you're searching for a correct reason to  justify the vote rather than for a vote to justify the correct reason. =\

Comment: I told you where in my opinion the problem is: 1) Clarify what you are doing and in which setup/library you expect answers 2) Explicitly ask for a programming solution. If you are not willing to make these changes in your question, feel free to wait for someone else who thinks that this questions should be reopened in the current state.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you are really seeking for input how to improve the question, but instead just try to argue why the five close voters are wrong. I already regret having tried to explain my reasons. It the same situation why a lot of people don't want to leave comments under the question anymore when downvoting or closevoting.

Comment: @BDL: Nah, I already updated the answer in response to Shadow's answer. The trouble I've been having with your reasoning is that it doesn't make any sense to me: you say "Linux" but I never said "Linux"; I never even asked anything OS-specific. You say I need to specify a "library" but I'm not asking about any library, just about the traditional C sockets API. You say the "only" indication that this was a programming question and not an OS/configuration was that I formatted "socket" as `socket`, which is factually wrong since I also had the `C` and `sockets` tags, etc....

Comment: @BDL: On the other hand, Shadow pointed out 2 very key things: (1) this is something that everyone expects to happen at the OS level, and that is why people don't expect this to be a programming question, and (2) given the above, people assume the tags are out-of-place, not the other way around. This differs **critically** from your response -- to quote yourself, you said: *"If you read that in a review queue, it looks as if you just want to connect to something and use strange formatting"*, which only implies the close votes were based on a cursory misreading and ignorance of the tags.

Comment: @Mehrdad I disagree with your conclusion. The close votes are result of not clear wording of the question and inappropriate tags.

Comment: @Shadow: That's fine, but then you're disagreeing with BDL and Cody Gray, not with me. I'm just quoting what they have said. BDL was the one who said "if you read that in a review queue, it looks as if {blah}", and Cody Gray was the one who said the fact that the answer is negative is the entire point of closing the question as off-topic. Neither of those implied the tags were inappropriate or that the question was unclear to someone who was actually taking the time to read the question (as opposed to just looking to quickly clear the review queue).